# Random 40px Padding in all Elements

Tags: html, css, padding

currently making a website for a friend of mine which has gone well so far using a column grid system for mobile responsiveness. However I am having a very large issue in that all of my content below the navbar appears to have a 40px padding (shown by Firebug) causing all content to be out of line. 
When looking through my CSS I can not seem to find where this padding comes from, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  body {
    background: url("background.jpg");
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
color: white;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 1200px;
}
#header-text {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}

#unforgettable {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#unforgettableH3 {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.fa {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.fa-twitter:hover {
    color: #5EA9DD;
    margin-right: 
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
    color: #3B5998;
}

.fa-pinterest:hover {
    color: #E0373F;
}

h3 {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background: rgb(183,183,183); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(183,183,183,1) 0%, rgba(94,94,94,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(183,183,183,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(94,94,94,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(183,183,183,1) 0%,rgba(94,94,94,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(183,183,183,1) 0%,rgba(94,94,94,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(183,183,183,1) 0%,rgba(94,94,94,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(183,183,183,1) 0%,rgba(94,94,94,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b7b7b7', endColorstr='#5e5e5e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
width: 100%;

}

ul.rig {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0px;
}
ul.rig li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 2.5% 2.5%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
ul.rig li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
ul.rig li h3 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
ul.rig li p {
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #999;
}


/* class for 2 columns */
ul.rig.columns-1 li {
    width: 97.5%; /* this value + 2.5 should = 100% */
}
/* class for 2 columns */
ul.rig.columns-2 li {
    width: 47.5%; /* this value + 2.5 should = 50% */
}
/* class for 3 columns */
ul.rig.columns-3 li {
    width: 30.83%; /* this value + 2.5 should = 33% */
}
/* class for 4 columns */
ul.rig.columns-4 li {
    width: 22.5%; /* this value + 2.5 should = 25% */
}

.list-center {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-left: -5px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.list-center > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px;
}

.navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    left: 10px;
    top: 11px;
    left: -6px;
}



@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    ul.grid-nav li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
    }
    ul.grid-nav li a {
        display: block;
    }
    ul.rig {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    ul.rig li {
        width: 100% !important; /* over-ride all li styles */
        margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: FireBug should also show you the element's attached classes and what classes give it the `padding`. You can go through that and determine which class is adding the excess padding.

Comment: Tough one to debug with what you have given us. Can you create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a fiddle or codepen? And what devices/browser is this happening on?

Comment: @LcLk the website is currently live at adamfenwickweb.co.uk I have tried putting an overall CSS piece which removes the 40px padding, which did improve the situation but was still not ideal. The Rig itself was disproportionate. http://jsfiddle.net/veg84r8f/

Comment: Are you using a [reset?](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)   Also, you have a lot of redundancy. Font-family, for example, only needs to be under the body selector.

Comment: @ZachCB I am not using any form of reset, currently the only code is what is within http://jsfiddle.net/veg84r8f/ however I have removed the addition Font-Family. If I set padding-left: 0px; within the CSS the issue is reduced creating a smaller gap between overall container and each box/column, however it still fixes itself in line with the right side of the container.

Comment: A 'fix' I have found is by padding. Padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 25px;which fixes it when viewed in a large browser but not in a smaller one, it then goes to far to the left. Which requires a large amount of media changes. Is that the best method for this situation? Or do you feel I should just remove rig method?

Comment: You're not talking about the ul's default padding, are you?